# Adding in custom buttons to a preference page

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

How can i add save and cancel buttons to a preference page so that it is saved when i click the save button?

Comment: Hi, looks like your question was closed for being too ambiguous. If you want to try to ask again, please explain what you've tried to do and where you're having trouble. Understand that we're not here to write code for you or to give you a tutorial on preferences, but to answer specific questions. Best of luck.